# Unicode code point escapes in regex literals - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, ecmascript-6, unicode-literals

Can this regex literal syntax having *Unicode escape sequence* syntax,

`var regpat= /^[\u0041-\u005A\u0061-\u007A\.\' \-]{2,15}/;`

be written using *Unicode code point escape* syntax(as shown below)?

`var regpat= /^[\u{41}-\u{5A}\u{61}-\u{7A}\u{1F4A9}\.\' \-]{2,15}/;`

*Note: Unicode code point escapes is used to simplify ES5-compatible surrogate pair syntax representing code point value more than `FFFF`*

Comment: `return "".match(/\u{1d306}/u)[0].length === 2;` to test for support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, according to [the spec](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-patterns-static-semantics-early-errors) this is now a valid escape sequence, however in order to enable support you must include the new **u** flag in the Regex definition:

```
var regpat = /^[\u{41}-\u{5A}\u{61}-\u{7A}\u{1F4A9}\.\' \-]{2,15}/u;
console.log(regpat.test("\u{41}\u{61}}"))
```

[Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=var%20regpat%20%3D%20%2F%5E%5B%5Cu%7B41%7D-%5Cu%7B5A%7D%5Cu%7B61%7D-%5Cu%7B7A%7D%5Cu%7B1F4A9%7D%5C.%5C'%20%5C-%5D%7B2%2C15%7D%2Fgui%3B%0Aconsole.log(regpat.test(%22%5Cu%7B41%7D%5Cu%7B61%7D%7D%22)))

Comment: `SyntaxError: invalid regular expression flag u` on *firefox 45.0a2* and *chrome 47.0*

Comment: @overexchange You can check the status of browser implementations [here](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-RegExp_y_and_u_flags). Babel transpiles regular expressions so is probably the only feasible option right now

Comment: Note that transpiled regular expressions may not work correctly when you deal with lone surrogates.

Comment: Note that the `\u{XXX}` syntax seems to be unsupported in IE11 (fine in Edge though)